# (sub) alignment within an align environment and number positioning

Tags: vertical-alignment

In the example below I try 3 different ways to achieve the same thing (align `=E(\sigma^{2}_{Y|X))` directly below `=E_{X}(V(\epsilon|X))+0` within the overall `align` environment. However I am unable to do so as well as try to understand the errors within each approach.

Also, how can I position the equation numbers on the left hand side of the equations (only for these two equations in the document)?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm} %for proof 

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
E(\epsilon)&=E_{X}(E(\epsilon|X))=E_{X}(0)=0 &\\
V(\epsilon)&=E_{X}(V(\epsilon|X))+V_{X}(\underbrace{E(\epsilon|X)}_\text{$=0$})  &=E_{X}(V(\epsilon|X))+0\\
& &=E(\sigma^{2}_{Y|X)) 
\end{alignat}


\begin{align}
E(\epsilon)&=E_{X}(E(\epsilon|X))=E_{X}(0)=0 &\\
V(\epsilon)&= \begin{split} E_{X}(V(\epsilon|X))+V_{X}(\underbrace{E(\epsilon|X)}_\text{$=0$})  &&=E_{X}(V(\epsilon|X))+0\\
&&=E(\sigma^{2}_{Y|X)) \end{split} 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
E(\epsilon)&=E_{X}(E(\epsilon|X))=E_{X}(0)=0 &\\
V(\epsilon)&= E_{X}(V(\epsilon|X))+V_{X}(\underbrace{E(\epsilon|X)}_\text{$=0$})  &&=E_{X}(V(\epsilon|X))+0\\
&&=E(\sigma^{2}_{Y|X))  
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align it properly I used the alignat environment correctly and changed a `)` to a `}` so it compiles without error.

Regarding the alignat environment: two columns are made like this:

```
col1 & col2
```

If you want an equation in each column with an own alignment:

```
term&=term & term&term
```

Thats all I did.

Managing the equation numbering temporarily I found the `tagsleft@true` respective `tagsright@true` in another forum. Dunno if this is great, but it works.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm} %for proof 

\makeatletter
\def\lefteqno{\tagsleft@true}\def\righteqno{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\lefteqno
\begin{alignat}{2}
E(\epsilon)&=E_{X}(E(\epsilon|X))=E_{X}(0)=0&&\\
V(\epsilon)&= E_{X}(V(\epsilon|X))+V_{X}(\underbrace{E(\epsilon|X)}_{=0})&&=E_{X}(V(\epsilon|X))+0\\
&&&=E(\sigma^{2}_{Y|X})
\end{alignat}
\righteqno
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways that hopefully correspond to what you want. I added some changes, from `\underbrace` to `underbracket`from `mathtools` (less heavy line if you want), and I defined an `\EV`, a `\Var` and a `\given` commands for conditional expected value and variance, that ensure variable-sized parentheses and vertical rule, with proper horizontal spacing (adapted from a `mathtools` example).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm} %for proof

%
\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\EV[1]{E}(){}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
#1}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Var[1]{V}(){}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
#1}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{align}
E(ϵ)&=E_{X}(\EV{ϵ \given X})=E_{X}(0)=0 &\\[1ex]
V(ϵ)&=\! \begin{aligned}[t] E_{X}(\Var{ϵ \given X})+V_{X}(\smash[b]{\underbracket[0.6pt]{\EV{ϵ \given X}}_\text{$=0$}}) &=E_{X}(\Var{ϵ \given X})\\
&=E(σ^{2}_{Y\vert X}) \end{aligned}
\end{align}
%
\begin{align}
E(ϵ)&=E_{X}(\EV{ϵ \given X})=E_{X}(0)=0 &\\[1ex]
V(ϵ)&= E_{X}(\Var{\epsilon\given X})+V_{X}(\smash[b]{\underbracket[0.6pt]{\EV{    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm} %for proof

%
\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\EV[1]{E}(){}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
#1}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Var[1]{V}(){}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
#1}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{align}
E(\epsilon)&=E_{X}(\EV{\epsilon\given X})=E_{X}(0)=0 &\\[1ex]
V(\epsilon)&=\! \begin{aligned}[t] E_{X}(\Var{\epsilon\given X})+V_{X}(\smash[b]{\underbracket[0.6pt]{\EV{\epsilon\given X}}_\text{$=0$}}) &=E_{X}(\Var{\epsilon\given X})\\
&=E(\sigma^{2}_{Y\vert X}) \end{aligned}
\end{align}
%
\begin{align}
E(\epsilon)&=E_{X}(\EV{\epsilon\given X})=E_{X}(0)=0 &\\[1ex]
V(\epsilon)&= E_{X}(\Var{\epsilon\given X})+V_{X}(\smash[b]{\underbracket[0.6pt]{\EV{\epsilon\given X}}_\text{$=0$}})\notag
\\ & =E_{X}(\Var{\epsilon\given X})\notag \\
&=E(\sigma^{2}_{Y\vert X})
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed for the great answer. Your suggestion for a `\given` much appreciated. Nevertheless due to compilation error, I modified it a bit: \providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\EV[1]{E(}{)}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\,\delimsize\vert\nonscript\,}
#1}

Comment: You will have trouble if you use the `\EV*` command: the purpose of this construction is to have variable-sized  parentheses in case of a large contents, either with the `*`  variant or with an optional argument (`\big`, `\Big`, &c). Did you update  your version of `mathtools`? The construction I propose is a relatively recent possibility.

Comment: Thanks Bernard. I see. I'm afraid I do not see `mathtools` either in the package manager or in the update wizard. Does it mean that I am using the latest version?

Comment: On the contrary: it was a component of the `mh` bundle, which was recently split into `mathtools` and `breqn`, with different maintainers. You're under MiKTeX, aren't you?

Comment: Hi @Bernard: Yep, indeed. I see from the package manager that that the `mh` package has been installed on 28-2-2014 (strangely though the options both for installing and uninstalling are not available, 'grayed out'). I don't see `mh` in the updatable package list. On the other hand I just installed `breqn`. Your thoughts, is it ok?

Comment: Well, you should see `mathtools`in the list, as `not installed` since previously it did not exist *per se*. You should synchronize the list with the present list (`Repository` menu, -> Synchronize). That done, you should see it in the (MPM, not MiKTeX Update) list. If if it's marked as installed, perhaps you should uninstall first, then install. Most probably, it will not be.